# Is it OK to return from an async method before the final await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a web page (aspx) that calls an async method in a class.  The async method looks something like this:

```
public async Task<MyThing> GetMyThing()
{
    MyThing thing = new MyThing();
    var stuff = await Repository.GetStuff();
    // apply stuff to thing.

    var morestuff = await Repository.GetMoreStuff();
    // apply more stuff to thing.

    if (someCondition)
    {
        return thing;
    }

    var yetMoreStuff = await Repository.GetYetMoreStuff();
    // apply yet more stuff

    return thing;
}
```

If the condition is met, I don't need the data from the last repository call.  Is the return before the final await going to cause me problems?

The reason I ask is I'm getting this error in the server application log, and I'm hunting for causes...

```
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
   at System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Comment: If you `return`, that `await` won't happen at all.

Comment: you need to step through that code. it is a NRE issue.

Comment: The error is not because of the threading but an exception within your Repository is bubbling up.

Comment: no, because the line will never get executed in that case

Comment: I understand the last repository call won't be executed - that's OK.  If the condition is met it doesn't need it.  The question is really will this cause the uncaught exception in the stack trace?

Comment: @Elton the uncaught exception is a null reference exception. you will need to debug the code and step through the lines to see where one of the instances being accessed is null. The sudo-code presented is not enough for us to provide much help.

Comment: I expect "ordinary" exceptions to be caught by the global error handler.  They aren't.  They're only showing up in the server windows application log.

Comment: @Nkosi I appreciate your help.  Unfortunately this is part of a very large solution with bits going back about 10 years.  Somewhere between two commits I did something bad.  I'm tracking through those now.  Usually my mistakes end up caught by the site's global error handler in testing.  Not this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to not run certain async operations. What you have is fine. What would *not* be so fine would be:

```
var notYetAwaited = DoSomethingAsync();

if (done) return "yay!";

await notYetAwaited;
```

i.e. an `async` operation that spans the return. This has less obvious and predictable behaviour, especially in sync-context environments.

Your problem is unlikely to be because of the return. It sounds like this is simply a NRE happening in your data code that is being surfaced in the sync-context callback.